# Meteor.Methods in one function, possible architecture solution

Tags: javascript, architecture, meteor

So I like to code with anonymous functions, and Meteor.methods break that for me. So I create a Meteor.Methods like this

//SERVER SIDE

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    //expose server methods.

        Meteor.methods({
            _SERVER_ : function(args){
                try{
                    var funcStr = args.func.split("."); //split on the function parameter
                    var scopeStr = funcStr[0]; //get the scope of the function
                    funcStr.splice(0,1); //remove the scope and get the deep path

                    var path = funcStr.join("."); //join the array and stick it with "."

                    console.log("util.funcString("+ scopeStr +","+ path +")(" + args.data + ");");

                    if( myapp.hasOwnProperty(scopeStr) ) //see if the function exist on myapp object
                    {
                        var scope = myapp[scopeStr]; //get the scope of the function
                        var response = util.funcString(scope, path)(args.data); //execute the function
                        console.log("myapp :" + args.func);

                        return response;

                    }else{
                        return "myapp don't have the method: " + args.func;
                    }

                }catch(e){
                    return "myapp has a wtf moment and its saying:" + e;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

So pretty much the function expect a call like this from the client. And its gonna call `myapp.page.add`

//CLIENT SIDE

```
    Meteor.call("_SERVER_",{
            func : "pages.add",
            data : page
        },function(err, value){
            insertNewPage(err,value);
        });
```

The benefit is now I can create a function in the server side like this.

//SERVER SIDE

```
   myapp.page = (function(){

        var privateVar = "private";

        //private
        function doSomething(){
        }

        //public via the return object
        function add(){
           console.log("called from client side");
        }

        return{
           add : add
        }
    })();
```

And my app now its more like modular, can be split very simple in different files and creating any namespace you want to.

THE QUESTION DO Im breaking any METEOR rule? its this is not secured? its a bad idea? Any suggestion is welcome, I'm still new in Meteor.

THANKS

Comment: Do you know that you can call `Meteor.methods` as many times as you want? So you can replicate the above with `Meteor.methods({"pages.add": function () {.... something ....}});`

Comment: no I didnt, thats why Im asking.

Comment: but Still you should have to declare the methods inside of Meteor.Methods for each of the functions. its not just one call for rule them all in the client side.

Comment: Whats the benefit of having one call instead of naming your methods directly?

Comment: I think its more clear the sintaxis of `myapp.page = (function())` that actually have multiple declarations of Meteor.Methods, form namespace perspective and clarity I think its quite better, easier to explain somebody else, etc. And Also its a more natural step form somebody that came from javascript background and its new in meteor. but of course is MHO

Comment: I think any architecture will work including yours, but someone who has used Meteor before would probably expect to see an explicit method for each function that will be called from the client. It's kind of like declaring routes for your REST API - it lets you easily see what is and isn't accessible from the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
myapp.page = (function(){

    var privateVar = "private";

    //private
    function doSomething(){
    }

    //public via the return object
    function add(){
       console.log("called from client side");
    }

    return{
       add : add
    }
})();
```

with:

```
myapp.page = (function(){

    var privateVar = "private";

    //private
    function doSomething(){
    }

    //public via the return object
    function add(){
       console.log("called from client side");
    }

    Meteor.methods({
        "page.add": add
    });
})();
```

If you want to call your methods with `Meteor.call("page.add", arg1, arg2)`.

Also, since Meteor automatically scopes your variables between files, you don't need the closure around privateVar.

Comment: This is way better that what I have. Good solution and nice tip.

Comment: The only problem I see now its that page.add its not a namespace, right? if you have for example `myapp2.page = ()` you cant use `page.add` now or am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the Method is defined. The entire Meteor project is one "app". If you want very detailed control of scoping, you probably want to put your code into a package, but I would be careful about not over-optimizing for modularity. You can also call Meteor methods from the server, so "page.add" will be accessible from anywhere in the app, client or server.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is obfuscating something Meteor has worked hard to do: making things simpler for developers. Meteor gives you the simplest, most direct way to get things done that I've seen since my early days in C. You just write clean code to do what you want. Meteor does this with web apps, and it's a very beautiful thing.

The bottom line: if you're adding layers of indirection in your Meteor code, you're likely overthinking the problem. Just relax. :-)  Keep the client stuff in client/, the server stuff in server/ and the shared stuff outside of them. Enjoy the simplicity.

Comment: Ok I will try to see the problem from a simple perspective. right now, this architecture works, but you are right maybe I will should try to go from a simple meteor way. I would like to see what other has done with the flexibility of Meteor and Javascript